# Understanding the behavior of unshare CLONE_NEWNS

Tags: namespaces, kernel

I wrote a small C program that simply does an unshare(CLONE_NEWNS) followed by system("bash").

The man page says that the process should have its own namespace. So, in the shell I tried unmount /cgroup (cgroup is mounted on the original machine).

When I do a mount in a shell on the machine, /cgroup is unmounted there too. Am I missing something here? I thought that CLONE_NEWNS was to let me unmount a file system from the process without affecting the main system.

Answer (score 5):

(As an aside, you didn't need to write a program - you could just use the `unshare(1)` utility).

It *is* unmounting the filesystem only in the new namespace, and leaving it mounted in the original - the problem is that `mount` uses `/etc/mtab` to produce the list of currently-mounted filesystems, and that's just an ordinary file that can be updated by the `mount` command in the new namespace.  This means that `/etc/mtab` gets out of synch with what's really going on (since there's only *one* `/etc/mtab`, but two mount namespaces).

Check `/proc/mounts` instead, to see what's actually mounted in the current namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly, this behavior is because of shared subtrees, where the parent mount of /cgroup (i.e., /), is marked as a "shared" mount that propagates mount and unmount events to its peers (other instances of /) in other namespaces. You can verify this by looking at the state of the / mount in /proc/self/mountinfo. This behavior has been most likely established by systemd, which reverts the kernel's default of "private" mounts to "shared". To get "private" behavior, you'd need to make / private using

```
mount --make-private /
```

See also https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=194388 and also https://lwn.net/Articles/689856/

Answer (score 0):

I did a test with unshare on fedora 19 kernel 3.10

unshare --mount /bin/bash

df -h /boot/

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

/dev/sda1       485M  238M  222M  52% /boot

umount /boot/

On a second shell

grep boot /proc/mounts

echo $?

1

Maybe i wrong something but the result is what i expected

Answer (score 0):

The unshare works in fedora, not on ubuntu, and at the same time, if you try just CLONE_NEWNS, it can not work,  seems unshare not quite same as directly call

clone(child_main, child_stack+STACK_SIZE,
      CLONE_NEWUTS | CLONE_NEWPID | CLONE_NEWNS | SIGCHLD, NULL);

this call, namespace operations can be seen from another namespace